# Encoding an EPPlus Excel file's byte array as a string in order to email it as an attachment using Postmark API

Tags: python, excel, email, epplus, postmark

I'm using EPPlus to create an Excel file with a couple of sheets and some data inside of it. I can convert it to a byte array using the ExcelPackage class's GetAsByteArray() method. I can also use the ExcelPackage constructor to make an excel file from a byte array like this:

```
var memoryStream = new MemoryStream(excelpackageByteArray)
var excelPackage = new ExcelPackage(memoryStream)
```

So I know that the byte array is actually representing an excel package/file, at least as far as EPPlus is concerned. So, I've been trying to send that byte array to an endpoint that creates an Attachment object. The object takes in three strings - one for contentType, one for content, and one for the file's name. For the contentType, I'm providing it the "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet" mime type. For content, I'm using Python's b64 module to b64encode the byte array and then pass that in as the content.

When I get the email, I see the excel file as an attachment and can download it. But when I try to open the file, I get the following error message:

"Excel cannot open the file because the file format or file extension is not valid. Verify that the file has not been corrupted and that the file extension matches the format of the file."

Given Postmark's Attachment object structure, how should I pass in the content? Specifically, how do I take an Excel file's byte array structure and turn it into some string that will allow Gmail or some other email service to properly decode it when I want to download and open the Excel file attachment? Postmark API specifically wants a base64-encoded string. But when I tried that with b64, it didn't work. Am I encoding the wrong thing? Instead of encoding the byte array, should I be encoding the excel package itself?

Comment: Afraid I am neither a python nor a postmark guy.  But if you take the attachment and save it as a file somewhere, rename name it from .xlsx to .zip, and open in WinZip or plain old windows explorer, does it open correctly?  (all office 2007 files are just zip files renamed)  If it does open, do you see a bunch of xml files?  Do they look formatted properly when viewed in notepad?

Comment: @Ernie Same issue when attempting to do that. If I want to have my endpoint return a byte array, do you know how can I make sure that the request object in my python script is the byte array rather than a string representing the byte array?